# how to pass xml as parameter using POST method and using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery + ajax to post data to the server and facing issues when xml string is passed.
I want to pass xml string eg., "`<test></test>`" as a parameter to the ajax function using POST method.
i am able to pass all other types, but not xml string.

Can somebody pls help me on this?

Comment: Adding the code snippet
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/GetResults",
        data: { inputxml: '<test></test>'},
        success: function(msg) {
            var data = JSON.parse(msg);
            alert(data.Message);
        },
       });

Answer (score 18):

In order to post xml or html to the server, you first have to **escape** it and then **decode** on the server.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/GetResults",
    data: { 
        inputxml: escape('<test></test>')
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        var data = JSON.parse(msg);
        alert(data.Message);
    },
});
```

on the server, you would then decode it by:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(inputxml);
```