# How to make HTTP POST request with XML content in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
var xmlString = 
            '<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes ?>'+
            '<Requests>'+
              '<Request type=GetMeasures>'+
                '<Filter>'+
                  '<BBox top=52 bottom=51.3 left=7.3 right=7.7 />'+
                '</Filter>'+
              '</Request>'+
            '</Requests>';
```

`$.ajax({
                       url: URL, 
                       type: "POST", 
                       ontentType: "text/xml", 
                       processData: false, 
                       data: xmlString_HasMeasures, 
                       success: function(response){
                            alert(response);
                       }
                    });`

So far doenst work for me. Can JQuery just pass key-value pairs?
Thanks!

Comment: have you try using xml only on the contentype?
btw you have an error on contentType it's missing a c

Comment: if you copy/pasted that from ure actuall code, then you should fix ontentType to contentType

Comment: also, is xmlString_HasMeasures supposed to be what you've declared to be xmlString?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass xml as parameter using POST method and using jquery ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920066/how-to-pass-xml-as-parameter-using-post-method-and-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: ok without typo it doesnt work either :-/ Yes xmlString_HasMeasures is my XML string. something wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "", 
    data: { inputxml: escape('<test></test>')}, 
    success: function(msg) { }, 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might as well use [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). And yes, because this will be [`x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29#Use_for_submitting_web_forms), you need a key to go with that XML value.

```
$.post(URL, {data: xmlString}, function (response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

Comment: Strange thing, that it isnt possible to just post a http-body.

Answer (score 0):

To post xml/html to the server, you have to **[escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)** it.

```
$.ajax({ url: URL, 
         type: "POST",
         data: {inputxml: escape(xmlString_HasMeasures)}, 
         success: function(response){ alert(response); } 
});
```