# doing a http POST to update a web page using c#

Tags: c#, http, post

URL of page to update (link will not work if you click on it, its just a sample): https://test-services.zzz111.org/yyy-9/center/api/rest/v1/pols/ZYPK

I'm assuming I need to do a POST on this URL.

Here's a sample of a request:

```
<PolChangeSet schemaVersion="2.1" username="ZZ@yyy999.com" description="Adding a note">
    <Attachment name="pic.jpg" contentType="image/jpeg">
        <Description/>
        <Location>https://services.zzz111.com/yyy-9/center/api/sdo/rest/v1/buckets/attachments/objects/6BD0C43B-4608-0EDE-F6DA-919097EFCABF.jpg</Location>
    </Attachment>
</PolChangeSet>
```

How would I go about sending this HTTP POST request to the URL?

Comment: Explain in more detail, what exactly you have done ? What headers and content you want to post to that url and etc... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to post on the backend, you can refer to this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx

And pass in the URI and the Paramaters as a string via xml

I edited the original source and added the contentType as an additional parameter. The XML type is `"application/xml"`

```
public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters, string contentType) 
{
   System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
   req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyString, true);
   //Add these, as we're doing a POST
   req.ContentType = contentType;
   req.Method = "POST";
   //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. Post'ed Faked Forms should be name=value&
   byte [] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
   req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
   System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream ();
   os.Write (bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
   os.Close ();
   System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
   if (resp== null) return null;
   System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
   return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

Comment: why would I need a proxy there?

Comment: Dont need the proxy, you can safely take it out. From the demo, its included so you can add a proxy server if required

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do this.

```
$.post(
    "action.php", 
    {"xmlString":xmlString}, 
    function (response){
        alert(response);
    }
);
```

Then you can parse the xml string to your object at server side.
Here are some examples about jquery post http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Or you can look about this answer, it is similar: [how to pass xml as parameter using POST method and using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920066/how-to-pass-xml-as-parameter-using-post-method-and-using-jquery-ajax)